# Update SSIS packages in SSMS jobs

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I'm working in a system made by someone else who left and left no documentation. He used SSIS packages that run automated in jobs to get data from various sources and put it in our data warehouse. Yesterday, the IP of one of our sources changed and while modifying it in the packages was no big deal, the jobs couldn't deal with it. The packages can run in SSDT just fine, but when a job is started, it can't autorize the user to login to the new IP. I found that you have to redeploy the packages, but this would override the SSMS solution and I don't want to lose all the jobs.

Comment: How are your packages saved?  Are they saved on a network drive, in the Integration Services Catalog, or in SQL Server.  It all depends on how the job is setup and where/how the packages are stored.

Comment: The packages are saved in a folder SSIS on the C drive of a server and in SSMS, I can see them aswell in a subfolder of SSISDB under Integration Services Catalog.

Comment: The job definition can override any of the configuration parameters of the SSIS package.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-package-and-project-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16#parameters-and-project-deployment-model

Comment: What do you mean by stored in SSMS? You can't store SSIS packages in SSMS; it's just an IDE-like application not a storage system.

Comment: When you upload a package it can be stored in multiple locations to be run from.  It can be stored in msdb.  See here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/save-packages?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @ThomA I meant that the SSIS packages are stored in a folder, but after modifying their connection managers, the jobs still didn't work so I assumed these were a different version of these same packages.

Answer (score 4):

As the packages are in the SSISDB, you're in luck, probably.

In SSMS, navigate to the SSISDB, expand it and find the project under the folder. Right click on the project and select Configure and click the Connection Managers tab

[image]

In the above screenshot, you can see the Values column is filled with regular type face. If you click the ellipses (...) on `ServerName` propert and change it from the current value of `.\dev2017` to `localhost\dev2017`, and the value would then show in a bold type face.

That means the default value (plain type face) has been override with a hard coded value. Click OK and the next invocation of the package run will use the newly configured values. If you re-deploy the project, it will retain those configured values. From a management perspective, SSISDB has been a huge win.

If you see values with an italicized value, then the previous developer used Environment Variables (but not OS level Environment Variables) which are probably in the Environments folder under the existing folder. But possibly not. The References tab (left side, under the currently highlighted Parameters) will direct you to the appropriate reference. Find it in the SSISDB tree and update the value there to your new IP.

You can confirm that on your next run by 1) it worked and 2) assuming standard logging, you'll have the connection values logged in the Execution reports.

### Hoofbeats: think horses, not zebras

The above is gonna be valid for most cases but I can envision plenty of patterns that break it. The most common of the uncommon scenarios are old SSIS developers who used Expressions to build a connection string and then used that to drive the Connection Manager's behaviour. No amount of overriding from outside the package will trump the internal overrides of a package. In that case, you'll have no choice but to update the packages with the new IP and redeploy.

It could be that they have a command line value set in the SQL Agent job which will provide an override on every execution. It's also an older trick for changing runtime values without actually changing the package. You'd have to script the job definition or click through the ...overrides/configuration? section to find out what they did.

### Wrapping it up

The good news with regard to your concern about deployment breaking the jobs is that they are independent. Your SSIS packages are a deployed unit called an .ispac file (fancy zip) that is stored in the SSISDB.

SQL Agent jobs are stored in the msdb and they merely contain the definition of  what task to perform (run this package), when to perform it (daily, 2200), as whom (proxy account Foo), the order of operations (step 1, step 2, on error step 3), and alerting (success, do nothing. Failure, page Operator)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I could solve the issue! I was worried that deploying the packages again might overwrite the something the jobs use as I thought the packages in SSIS were somehow different than the ones in SSISDB since modifying their connection managers didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @billinkc high quality answer! I have a question. how is the communication ensured between a package and a job? One of them is stored in SSIS DB Catalog and another in MSDB which means "Integration Services Engine"  Thanks!